# Creating a LaTeX document in R: formatting a template

Tags: r, parsing, templates, latex, knitr

There're several options for mixing R and LaTeX. `knitr` allows putting R code in tex, but sometimes it's more comfortable to work in another direction: to build the entire tex code in the R script.

Say, we have a template of an entire tex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{ {{author_name}} }
...
{{table_1}}

\end{document}
```

What's the best way to combine it with R? I.e., the goal is to replace tags within the template with R output. Here `whisker` and `gsubfn` looks like a solution, but how to make sure that `whisker.render` and `fn$paste` won't conflict with LaTeX markup and replace only their own tags? E.g., any inline math `$a$` in the template can be interpreted as a variable `a` by `fn$paste`?

Perhaps, there're better ways of replacing tags in the LaTeX template?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with a small minimal example? giving a latex doc what is the expected output after parsing?

Comment: @agstudy Sorry for being imprecise. My goal is to have a template I can edit separately from R code, but then run an R script to replace all tags like `table_1` with respective R output (a table formatted in LaTeX). And I'm interested in the optimal way of writing this template, so to avoid compatibility issues between R and LaTeX code. So far I'm proceeding with `whisker` and braces, but it's still leaves much problems, like TeX characters within R strings inserted in the template.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you get more specific about the output you seek and the template. My gut feel is that this is a job for `brew` + `knit`.

Comment: @Ramnath Thank you. I'll try the options you've suggested, and will be more specific.